# Load UML Statechart Model with EMF that has an applied profile

Tags: java, eclipse, profile, eclipse-emf

I am trying to load a UML model stored as XMI via the eclipse MDT/UML2 implementation.

It is the model of a statechart, that has a profile attached and a stereotype added to this profile that is used to model transitions with priorities.

Loading the *.uml file with eclipse EMF framework is fine.

I now want to load this *.uml file with a standalone java project. I want to access all the Elements of the Model with the applied stereotypes.

I can get everything, but not the Stereotypes. I'm sure they have not been loaded from the *.uml file.

The code I use:

```
URI uri = URI.createURI("model.uml");

ResourceSet set = new ResourceSetImpl();

set.getPackageRegistry().put(UMLPackage.eNS_URI, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);

set.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);

set.createResource(uri);

Resource r = set.getResource(uri, true);

Model model = (Model) EcoreUtil.getObjectByType(r.getContents(), UMLPackage.Literals.MODEL);
```

I can now access everything the model gives me via `model.allOwnedElements()`.
I find the Profile that is stored with the actual model in the *.uml file, but the
Stereotypes are not attached to the Elements in the model.

I think I'm missing something that has to be added to the resource set via `getPackageRegistry() and getResourceFactoryRegistry()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a plugin project instead.